# Android categorize notification under Silent notifications

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-notifications, background-process

I'm running a persistent task in the background and need to show a notification that my app is running a service (From Android Oreo & above)

However, I would like to see the notification under the **Silent notifications** category rather than **Alerting notifications** as the notification seems intrusive to the user. I've seen various applications do this and was wondering how I could achieve the same.

**Output I would like**
[image]

I've tried meddling with the `setPriority` and `.setCategory` methods but still get the same result.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SYSTEM)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification); //To start the service
```

Comment: your issue is notification shows but  Silent notifications right..?

Comment: @BADSHAH yes exactly

Comment: pls read this link : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications

Comment: What version of Android are you running?

Answer (score 0):

On Samsung, foreground service notifications are not placed under the "Silent Notifications" even if their notification channel is set to `IMPORTANCE_MIN` or `IMPORTANCE_LOW`.

Here's a table:

```
+--------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| IMPORTANCE_* | Normal Notification    | Foreground Service     |
|              |                        | Notification           |
+--------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| MIN          | Silent Notifications   | Alerting Notifications |
+--------------+                        |                        |
| LOW          |                        |                        |
+--------------+------------------------+                        |
| DEFAULT      | Alerting Notifications |                        |
+--------------+                        |                        |
| HIGH         |                        |                        |
+--------------+                        |                        |
| MAX          |                        |                        |
+--------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

However, Samsung users are free to 'force' the system to place the foreground service notifications under "Silent Notifications" by turning on the "Minimize Notifications" setting of the notification's notification channel.

Notes:

- "Minimize Notifications" is only visible on notification channels whose importance is equal to `IMPORTANCE_MIN` or `IMPORTANCE_LOW` or when the user sets the notification channel to "Silent".
- The icon of the foreground service notification will still be shown on the status bar even if "Minimize Notifications" is on.